# Finding Next Select Control on HTML page using Selenium in VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net, selenium, xpath

On my Webpage I have three Dropdown Controls. When First Option is selected in the First Combo, the Second Combo Control Gets Populated and similarly on selecting an Option in the Second Combo populates the Third Combo Control.

Each Combo Control has a  above it. Using Selenium in VB.net, I am able to find the First Combo Control and iterate through each Option Available. The Challenge I am facing is that, the label on Second and third Combo gets its text from the the Selected Option of the First and Second Combos, respectively. However, the XPath changes randomly with each option selected due to which the FindElement(By.Xpath) fails.

The example Combos are available this Link [Set of Three Combos](https://mes.gov.in/en/tenders)

I tried using the following VB.net Code

```
Dim CWEstring = "./following-sibling::select"
GE = New SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(CWEstring)))
```

and

```
Dim GEString = "./following-sibling::select"
GE = New SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(GEString )))
```

I did my research for few days but couldn't get the answer, so posting here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Downloaded the webpage `Source` and Edited the code to bear minimum `HTML` content so that all three Combo Controls are visible and save the html content as a .htm file on local disk.
Using chrome I opened the `.htm` file. Then Using `MS-Excel` `From Web` under Data tab **Scraped** the data from the local .htm file.

Now I had all values under one `Column Header` `name`. I converted all values under column `name` into an array.

Using `VB.net` and `Selenium` technology, I iterated through each `combo` control and saved the data to a New `Excel` File.

More Challenges came to fore. Therefore, I used `Try...Catch` method to `trap` the `error` and `Continue` the Iterations (Loops).

And now I have all the values the way I wanted them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `xpath` to identify the element.

1st dropdwon:

```
//select[@id='edit-field-select-zone2-value']
```

2nd Dropdown:

```
//select[@id='edit-field-cce-army-no-1dinjan-cwe-tid']
```

3rd dropdown:

```
//select[@id='edit-field-pm-khonsa-tid']
```

Please note you have to provide some **wait** after selecting each `dropdown` item to appear **next** `dropdown` on the webpage.

Comment: i already tried this but it wont work as the xpath values are not systematic as we progress...